# Как пишется Блетчли-парк?

Tags: прописная-строчная, топонимика

Как пишется топоним Блетчли-Парк. Дефис, скорее всего, должен быть, но непонятно, с прописной ли буквы начинается слово "парк"?

Comment: @Sergey Kim, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Блетчли-Парк.

Comment: спасибо. а на какой источник вы опираетесь?

Comment: Здесь слово ''Парк'' является не нарицательным именем, а именем собственным составного названия. См.:[Википедия](http://www.quickiwiki.com/ru/%C1%EB%E5%F2%F7%EB%E8-%EF%E0%F0%EA)

Comment: Сержик, парк, он и в Африке парк: ***Блетчли-парк (англ. Bletchley Park), также известный как Station X — особняк, расположенный в Блетчли (в городе Милтон Кинс) в историческом и церемониальном графстве Бакингемшир в центре Англии. В период Второй мировой войны в Блетчли-парке располагалось главное шифровальное подразделение Великобритании — Правительственная школа кодов и шифров...*** С Новым годом! )))

Comment: Вот источник: https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.cf578291-625cfc78-031966de-74722d776562/https/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bletchley_park  Но варианты письма встречаются разные. Прописная буква  определяется тем, что это не парк в обычном понимании этого слова, а поместье, то есть условное название. В этом случае дефис может отсутствовать. В противном случае (для названия обычного парка) надо писать через дефис и со строчной буквы.